# How to update a table using D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an html document with the following section:

```
 <select id="avgSalesTable" onchange="createTable();">
    <option>---</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
```

And I have a JavaScript file with the following section:

```
function createTable(year) {

   var filtered_year = document.getElementById("avgSalesTable").value;

   console.log(filtered_year)

   var filtered_data = realEstateData.filter(x => x.year === filtered_year)

   console.log(filtered_data)

   for (var i = 0; i < filtered_data.length; i++) {
        var row = d3.select('tbody').append('tr');
        row.append('td').html(filtered_data[i].Borough);
        row.append('td').html(filtered_data[i].averagePrice1familyHome);

   }
  }
createTable(2016)
```

I want the table to change as a new selection in the dropdown menu is made. However, the result that I am getting is that new rows are appended to the previous table.

Here is the realEstateData file:

```
var realEstateData = [

{
    year: "2018",
    Borough: "Bronx",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 499060
},

{
    year: "2016",
    Borough: "Bronx",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 478379
},

//--------------
{
    year: "2018",
    Borough: "Manhattan",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 8235346
},

{
    year: "2016",
    Borough: "Manhattan",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 8176576
},


//--------------
{
    year: "2018",
    Borough: "Brooklyn",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 980737
},


{
    year: "2016",
    Borough: "Brooklyn",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 876864
},

//--------------

{
    year: "2018",
    Borough: "Queens",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 645921
},

{
    year: "2016",
    Borough: "Queens",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 613139
},



//--------------

{
    year: "2018",
    Borough: "Staten Island",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 520214
},

{
    year: "2016",
    Borough: "Staten Island",
    averagePrice1familyHome: 483340
},
//--------------
];
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3` is not used as it should in the existing code: d3's [`data join`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) feature is not used, it would provide the benefit of facilitating the management of changes in the data.

A quick fix is to empty the table before appending rows. This can be done by adding the following right before the `for` loop:

```
d3.select('tbody').html('')
```

Otherwise, the code should be refactored, main steps being:

- bind the dataset to the d3 selection using `selection.data()`
- use [`selection.join()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#joining-data) to update the table as wanted: add new relevant rows, remove obsolete rows.
- in case the volume of data is reasonable, it makes sense to add all data in the table once at page load, and only toggle each row's visibility to filter.
- rename `createTable` to `updateTable` (nice to have)